# Can I gain some efficiency by declaring appropriate members "static" in Android Activity

Tags: android, static, singleton, android-activity

If an Activity is a singleton in practice, I think I can gain some efficiency by declaring appropriate members "static", with zero risk.  Yes?

Comment: P.S> I earned 1000 views badge with this question.. if you find it useful please support the SO process by marking the question - click the UP arrow.  Thanks

Comment: Activity (in general) is not a singleton.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [Android documentation says](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#lmodes) -

> there's never more than one instance
>   of a "singleTask" or "singleInstance"
>   activity, so that instance is expected
>   to handle all new intents.

This means **you can use static members**.

Besides, a `standard` or `singleTop` should have **thread-safe static members only**. Suppose the current activity stack is A-B-C-D. If the arriving intent is for an activity of type B which is in "standard" or "singleTop" mode. A new instance of B would be launched as (since B is not at the top of the stack), so the resulting stack would be A-B-C-D-B.

Comment: interesting -- I always wondered why sharing state via static fields doesn't work, sometimes a field would suddenly turn null. I didn't declare these fields volatile, is that the reason? But why? I thought there's only a single UI thread?

Comment: @Matthias : Perhaps Android might use a new process to launch the same activity. http://android-developers.blogspot.dk/2010/04/multitasking-android-way.html

Answer (score 3):

One thing please DO NOT use singleTask or singleInstance for this purpose.  The activity launch flags are there to control how activity stacks behave.  They have visible impact on the user interaction with your activity (making it non-standard).  Those modes are intended to be used when you want that kind of user interaction, they should NOT be used to change the implementation details of your app.

Comment: So, Activities should NOT use static members except where they would be appropriate in multi-instance operation...

I'd hoped that "that kind of user interaction" would be made clear to me by the Android documentation (ref Ankit's post up top) but it seems I'm a bit thick.. guess I'll post a new question.

Comment: i did not get it, so using static would be much better? cause i am having a problem with the private constructor

Answer (score 1):

No. The same `Activity` can be started multiple times in the same process. For example, you can try starting an `Activity` from itself, when clicking a button.

Comment: you can declare activity's property in manifest as singleInstance/singleTop/singleTask to ensure one instance only.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an Activity can be a "singleton" if you ensure that an instance of Activity A isn't started while another instance of Activity A is in the activity stack (an instance of Activity A could technically start another instance of itself).

Comment: That's basically saying an `Activity` is a singleton if you ensure it is one. That doesn't make it a singleton.

Comment: That's true, but the ultimate question is if it can be a singleton in practice, which it can be. So in all practicality, static members can be safely used if the developer maintains a maximum of 1 instance, even without a singleton design pattern. (Personally I prefer practicality over technicality, but both of our answers are valid :) )

Comment: Thanks Felix and Andy.. seems Ankit has this one :)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [activity property launchMode at android.developer page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode).

**Quote**: "***standard*** is the default mode and is appropriate for most types of activities. ***SingleTop*** is also a common and useful launch mode for many types of activities. The other modes — ***singleTask*** and ***singleInstance*** — are not appropriate for most applications, since they result in an interaction model that is likely to be unfamiliar to users and is very different from most other applications."