# Open multiple instances of an activity from multiple instances of same appwidget

Tags: java, android

I have a widget which opens up a settings Activity when clicked..Right now if the user adds multiple instances of the widget and click them they all opens up the same activity with same data and same `SharedPreferences`.

in my `onReceive()` i have

```
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.mytv, pendingIntent);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisAppWidget, views);
```

What I want is to open the settings Activity as a separate instance with independent `SharedPreferences`...
Is there a way?

Comment: Android activity follow singleton pattern....http://stackoverflow.com/a/3399898/1075066

Comment: You can have 2 different Activity/Class with same layout for your purpose

Comment: @Vincent what if the user will put n- number of widgets ? Your idea is not suitable for this

Comment: you cannot avoid users from adding more widgets.However you can use SharedPreference/Db to keep track of what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that activity just pass the appwidget id to that activity when opening it.
Use the appwidget id for creating separate shared preference files for every widget instance or just use a single shared pref file but where you need different settings for the widget just create some key and append the widget id for that key e.g "sort_order_"+appWidgetId. Just not forget to delete the preference file or the keys belonging to that appwidget when the widget was been removed from the screen.